# With Sinatra+Thin, how to get a specific SSL client certificate suggestion during login?

Tags: ssl, sinatra, client-certificates, thin, eventmachine

I am running a small sinatra application which re-uses a company-wide client certificate every employee has already installed (signed by an internal SSO_CA).
My Sinatra/Thin combination is using the server certificate signed by an internal company CA but is expecting the client certificate signed by SSO_CA.

Technically this worked fine until we got a second self-signed client certificate on our PCs. The browser is unsure which certificate to use and is guessing the wrong one, most users do not read and use the new certificate, which ends in a 403 error.

In addition, browsers remember the decision and you have to explain to many people how to reset the SSL state.

**=> Sinatra / Thin/ Eventmachine are not providing an option like `:SSLCACertificateFiles '/usr/sinatra/certs/SSO_CA.crt'`
to tell the browser "please show up with client certificate from SSO_CA"**

Webrick has it but this is not the right choice for "production". Moving to Nginx feels strange as I cannot be the first having this issue in Thin.
I remember there was somewhere in a forum (cannot find it again) someone telling me that the feature is missing but I found this before I had an understanding that this is going to be my problem as well.

Has anybody an idea how to force Thin/Eventmachine to forward a specific CA suggestion for client certificate? It is not `:SSLCACertificateFiles`, I tried it already.

Comment: I know nothing about Ruby/Sinatra/Webrick. But studying https://github.com/ruby/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/ssl.rb in the comments I see: `:SSLClientCA`, `:SSLExtraChainCert`, `:SSLCACertificateFile` (note: no final `s`, so I do not know if you have a typo in your question), and `:SSLCACertificatePath` and `:SSLCertificateStore`. None of those help?

Comment: With the same caveat, for `thin`, I see in https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/8df953e776e0a8153139b75eae919811dca45f92/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb : `:cert_chain_file => @options[:ssl_cert_file]`

Comment: I already provide a cert chain... it seems that the combination off Eventmachine + Thin is not fully working hand in hand in ssl area. Most people move to ngix + unicorn or puma.... at the end i need user information from CN feld of the client... it could be soo easy :(